# prolog: parsing a sentence and generating a response in a simple language parser

Tags: parsing, syntax, prolog

so far I have the following working:

```
gen_phrase(S1,S3,Cr) :- noun_phrase(S1,S2,Cr1), verb_phrase(S2,S3,Cr2),
                        append([Cr1],[Cr2],Cr),add_rule(Cr).

question_phrase(S1,S5,Cr) :- ist(S1,S2),noun_phrase(S2,S3,Cr1),
                             noun_phrase(S3,S4,Cr2),
                             append([Cr1],[Cr2],Cr).

add_rule([X,Y]) :-
    Fact =.. [Y, X],
    assertz(Fact).
```

Given test run, code generates following:

```
1 ?- gen_phrase([the,comp456,is,a,computing,course],S3,Cr).
S3 = []
Cr = [comp456, computing_course].
```

add_rule(Cr) asserts existence of predicate computing_course(comp456).
Now what I would like to do is ask a question:

```
4 ?- question_phrase([is,the,comp456,a,computing,course],X,Cr).
Cr = [comp456, computing_course] .
```

What I need to do is extract computing_course and comp456, which I can do, then convert it into form accepted by prolog. This should look like Y(X) where Y = computing_course is a predicate and X = comp456 is atom. The result should be something similar to:

```
2 ?- computing_course(comp456).
true.
```

And later on for questions like "What are computing courses":

```
3 ?- computing_course(X).
X = comp456.
```

I thought about using assertz, however I still do not know how to call predicate once it is constructed. I am having hard time finding what steps need to be taken to accomplish this. (Using swi-prolog).

Edit: I have realized that there is a predicate call(). However I would like to construct something like this:

```
ask([X,Y]) :- call(Y(X)).

2 ?- gen_phrase([a,comp456,is,a,computing,course],S3,Cr).
S3 = [],
Cr = [comp456, computing_course] 

4 ?- question_phrase([is,the,comp456,a,computing,course],X,Cr),ask(Cr).
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: ask/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

It doesn't appear that such call() is syntactically correct. Would be good to know if this is at all possible and how.

Answer (score 0):

[call/N](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call/2) it's what you need (here N == 2):

```
ask([X,Y]) :- call(Y,X).
```

You could as well use something very similar to what you already use in `add_rule/1`:

```
ask([X,Y]) :- C =.. [Y,X], call(C).
```

The first form it's more efficient, and standardized also.